# Redirect telnet 23 to COM Port via WIFI

Tags: redirect, bluetooth, serial-port, wifi, can-bus

I bought an Bluetooth  ELM327 to read codes out of my cars diagnostic ports

I connect to it via Bluetooth in windows and it makes a serial-over-bluetooth com port 4 
which any application running on my windows will connect quite happily.

I then found a few apps for the iphone and android etc that connect to these ELM gadgets via WIFI and not Bluetooth (because for some reason you cannot pair to these devices of iphone)

Now obviously I can buy a WIFI enabled ELM327 - but it costs £130 and my Bluetooth one cost £15

So after reading about this a bit I found out that the WIFI enabled ones you connect up as ad-hoc network and the smartphone(iphone) app tenets in port 23 that relays normal serial commands.

So obviously in the WIFI enabled one there must be some processor that runs an nano-os with telnet and some rs-323 translators and not sure what else.

How, using Windows 7 will i be able to relay any incoming WIFI requests for Telnet port 23 to my COM 4 that is connected to my Bluetooth ELM327 ..

As this is surely all that is needed by the Smartphone app.

Comment: So.. its just iPhone that decided not to allow serial-over-bluetooth. All other smartphones pair properly. Apparently if you jailbreak the iPhone and install ibluetooth from cydia you can establish serial-over-bt and this should solve my problem. Whoop

Comment: Actually you need to downlaod btstackGPS. this is a serial communicator only will try later hope it works. Or i will jsut install andrioid on my iphone instead...jezuz

Comment: just not possible with iphone - So my question still stands how to redirect telnet <> com4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no feature built in to Windows (or any other platform I know of) for such a scenario.

It would be fairly straightforward however to write a program to listen on port 23 and open a bluetooth connection when connected to, and then forward the data received on each connection out onto the other.

For instance one could use my .NET library 32feet.NET (e.g. http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=General%20Bluetooth%20Data%20Connections etc etc) along with TcpListener from the .NET framework class libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to connect using a Bluetooth library like suggested ... because you are already connected to the device and have COM4 exposed to you. SO all you have todo is use a telnet library and translate and handle the handshake then realy the infomation as serial data.